# Read-Only merge fields in Word C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I have a requirement to create read-only merge fields in Word.

I've already tried using the Locked property which can be seen below.The description of this property states - *When a field is locked you cannot update field results* which sounds like a perfect fit for my problem but this doesn't seem to be working

Below is the code i use to add the merge field to MS Word:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;  

Word.Range currentRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
Word.MailMerge merge = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.MailMerge;
merge.Fields.Add(currentRange, selectedNode.LocalName).Locked = true;
```

Once I run the code above and the field is created in Word, I am still able to right click it and select "Edit Field" where I can potentially rename the field or perform other changes without getting any errors or preventions from Word.

[image: Edit Field is enabled]

If anyone implemented something like this before, please share your knowledge.

Here is some insight on the technologies:

- The solution is targeted at MS Word Office 2010
- It must be written in .NET C# 3.5
- Cannot use Open Xml SDK, the fix must be performed using Office Interop
- The solution must achieve the desired goals without making the whole document read-only

Comment: wouldn't you still need to set the word document variable read-only property to True;
i.e so if your object instance is named objDoc do you still need to do objDoc.readonly = true; ..?

Comment: The word document still needs to be editable, ammended my question to reflect this. Have a look at the answer I've posted,it solves the problem quite nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the replies, however I needed to only make the merge fields read-only the rest of the document should still stay as is.

A colleague of mine found a nice way to achieve what I was looking for, just sharing it in case someone else may need this functionality:

All you need to do is create a ContentControl object and add your merge field to the content control.
Set the LockContents property to true. This property is used to determine whether a user is allowed to edit the contents of a content control.

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

object missing = System.Type.Missing;

Word.Selection PosRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ContentControl cntCtrl;
cntCtrl = PosRange.Range.ContentControls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, ref missing);

object fldType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField;
object fldText = "Employee";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field fld = cntCtrl.Range.Fields.Add(cntCtrl.Range, ref fldType, ref fldText);
cntCtrl.LockContents = true;
```

In the image below a merge field is hosted inside a content control, note users are now unable to edit the field

[image: Update and Edit field are disabled]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Locked property will only prevent the *value* of the field from changing, which I'm assuming is not what you want.

The only way I know to prevent the field *code* from changing is to protect the document. The fields themselves should still be updatable.